What does Baldwin's parenthetical "So much for states' rights" mean?
TW: Racial violence.
Regarding Elijah Muhammad, the leader of the Nation of Islam, James Baldwin writes:

He is not an overnight sensation, and we owe his ministry, I am told, to the fact that when he was a child of six or so, his father was lynched before his eyes. (So much for states' rights.)
Baldwin, James. "Down at the Cross: Letter from a Region of my Mind." 1962. The Fire Next Time. 1963. New York: Modern Library, 1995. pp. 13–105. Quotation is from pp. 49–50. 

What does James Baldwin mean by his dismissive statement, "So much for states' rights"? I know that invoking states' rights is considered a conservative dog whistle. For example, David Greenberg argues in a Slate Magazine article that Reagan's use of the term in a 1980 speech was "an endorsement of the white South's wish to reverse the 20-year-old trend of using federal laws (and troops when necessary) to protect the rights of African-Americans." But I'm not sure exactly how Baldwin's parenthetical remark relates to his preceding sentence about the horrific death of Elijah Muhammad's father.
